# Map a tbl of hyperlinks into read_html

Tags: r, rvest, purrr

I have a tibble containing one column which stores hyperlinks in each column. Now I want to map over these links using map_dfr, passing the links one after another through `read_html(.x[.x]) %>% 
    html_node(".body-copy-lg") %>% html_text`. If I do so I always end up with the error :

> > Error in doc_parse_file(con, encoding = encoding, as_html = as_html, options = options) : 
> >       Expecting a single string value: [type=character; extent=3].

Which tells me that the read_html basically says: " Hey stop throwing more than one string at the same time on me."

So did I make a mistake in the mapper? Is this a bug? I really can't see why the mapper-function does not grab each element one after another.

What I tried so far :

```
target_regex <- "(xtm)|((k|K)(i|I|1|11)(d|D)(n|N).)|(Ar<e)\\s(you)\\s(in)| 
(LOAN)|(AR(\\s|\\S)[0-9])|((B|b)(i|1|l)tc.)|(Coupon)|(Plastic.King)|(organs)|(SILI)|(Electric.Cigarette.Machine)"

adverts <- function(df) df[!grepl(target_regex, df$...1,perl = T), ]

bribe <- read_html(paste("http://ipaidabribe.com/reports/paid?page", 10, sep = "="))

report <- map(".read-more", ~html_nodes(bribe, .x) %>% 
    html_attr(.x[[1]][[1]][[1]], name = "href"))[[1]] %>% 
    as_tibble(.name_repair = "unique") %>% 
    bind_rows() %>% 
    rename( ...1 = value) %>% 
    adverts() %>%
    map_dfr(~read_html(.x[.x]) %>%  
    html_node(".body-copy-lg") %>% 
    html_text)
```

Do not mind the call of `rename()` which is basically something what needed to be done to make the `adverts` usable in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You're forgetting that most functions in R are vectorized, and that using `map` or `apply` functions is unnecessary.  In your case, it is needed in the final step of getting the html text.

The syntax your are using in `map` is also puzzling, and I think you should review `?map` to get a better handle on it.   For instance, you use multiple `.x` or extracted values where you should just be using `.x` to refer to the sub-element of the object you are iterating over.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

target_regex <- "(xtm)|((k|K)(i|I|1|11)(d|D)(n|N).)|(Ar<e)\\s(you)\\s(in)| 
(LOAN)|(AR(\\s|\\S)[0-9])|((B|b)(i|1|l)tc.)|(Coupon)|(Plastic.King)|(organs)|(SILI)|(Electric.Cigarette.Machine)"

adverts <- function(df) df[!grepl(target_regex, df$...1,perl = T), ]

bribe <- read_html(paste("http://ipaidabribe.com/reports/paid?page", 10, sep = "="))

report <- html_nodes(bribe, ".read-more") %>% 
  html_attr("href") %>% 
  as_tibble(.name_repair = "unique") %>% 
  filter(str_detect(value, target_regex, negate = TRUE)) %>% 
  mutate(text = map_chr(value, ~read_html(.x) %>%  
                          html_node(".body-copy-lg") %>% 
                          html_text))

result

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  value                                                            text                                                                                                        
  <chr>                                                            <chr>                                                                                                       
1 http://ipaidabribe.com/reports/paid/paid-bribe-to-settle-matter… "\r\n                    Place: Nelamangala Police Station, Bangalore\nDate of incident:  5th Jan 2020, 3PM…
2 http://ipaidabribe.com/reports/paid/paid-500-rs-bribe-at-nizamu… "\r\n                        My Brother Mahesh Prasad travelling on PNR number 4822171124 train no 12721 Ni…
3 http://ipaidabribe.com/reports/paid/drone-air-follow-focus-wire… "\r\n                    This new Silencer Air+ is a tremendously versatile and resourceful follow focus, z…
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this precise, clear and helpful answer. As my approach might show : I'am relatively unexperienced in programming and R especially. You really encouraged me to study the basics and the package documentation of purrr!

Comment: If I run your code now for the second time I recieve the error :
`Error: C stack usage 15926112 is too close to the limit` Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: It seems that the filter function you called produces infinite recursion but I dont know why. Maybe you can find the problem.